# How can I remove session related information from database when the session gets killed?

Tags: java, session

I have web application as soon as a user logs in the session id, username and timestamp gets inserted to database.

But when the browser crashes or the session is killed the entry in the Db remains. So How to remove this entry in the database?

Comment: why save session information in db ? :-/

Comment: to keep track of all the concurrent users who have logged in.

Comment: @shasho27: Don't add it in db. Session is enough for this kind of information.

Comment: @harry if he tries to list online users or similar, it's not @shashi27 keep this information in memory instead (using HttpSessionListener as described by @Apache Fan). To do some simple math: 10,000 concurrent sessions and 0,1 KB/session require 1 MB of memory - no need to put this transient and frequently accessed information into DB

Comment: @sfussenegger - Saving it in memory will cause problems if you have a cluster. Then you will get inconsistent results. But i agree Database is not the way to go. Maybe use something like high availability OSCache to store this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to define a HttpSessionListener

```
<listener>
     <listener-class>mypackage.MySessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The listener code is called whenever a session is created and destroyed.

```
package mypackage;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.Date;


public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener
{
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se)
    {
           // DO CREATION LOGIC
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)
    {

             HttpSession session = se.getSession();
           // PERFORM DELETION LOGIC
    }
}
```

Your listener class has to implement the HttpSessionListener interface. Rest is self explanatory.